# How to receive upon clicking tableviewcell specific Firebase data to the viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, segue

I am building a swift application through the use of firebase, within my firebase database I have (childs) restaurants with the information. I have successfully integrated firebase to my project and populating my tableview with firebase data with images through the use of SDWebImage. However now I am stuck with another issues relating the use of segue and retrieving correct data from my firebase database upon clicking my tableview cell. In the past I have successfully built several swift and objective-c tableviews with the detailViewControllers, but it is my first experience with firebase. 
Thank you in advance :)
Here below I my passing my codes from xcode:

**Main Tableview:**
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SDWebImage

class MainTableVC: UITableViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var MenuBar: UIBarButtonItem!



var barName = [String]()
var barMainImage = [String]()
var barAddress = [String]()





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)



    MenuBar.target = self.revealViewController()
    MenuBar.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())


    getDataFromServer()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func getDataFromServer(){
    Database.database().reference().child("aktau").observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let values = snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary
        let posts = values["barmain"] as! NSDictionary
        let postIDs = posts.allKeys
        for id in postIDs{
            let singlePost = posts[id] as! NSDictionary
            self.barName.append(singlePost["barname"] as! String)
            self.barAddress.append(singlePost["baraddress"] as! String)
            self.barMainImage.append(singlePost["barmainimage"] as! String)

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
     return barName.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RestoCell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerCell
    cell.RestName.text = barName[indexPath.row]
    cell.RestAddress.text = barAddress[indexPath.row]
    cell.RestImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: barMainImage[indexPath.row]))


    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "DetailView") {

        let VC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        VC.RestNameData = barName


}
```

}
}
**issue with barName** -

> Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?'

**And my detailViewController** 
In Addition to the BarName, BarAddress and BarMainImage - I would like to include short bar information and opening time.

import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SDWebImage

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var MyScroll: UIScrollView!




@IBOutlet weak var RestDetailView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var restName: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var restTypeOfFood: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var restClockImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var restOpenHours: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var restInfoView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var averagePrice: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var InfoAboutRest: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var FullAddressLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var OpeningHoursLabel: UILabel!

var RestNameData: String?






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.RestDetailView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.RestDetailView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.restInfoView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.restInfoView.layer.borderWidth = 1

    if RestNameData.text == "" {

    }

}
```

}

**My Firebase Database Tree**:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA3FP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to fix problem you're facing. First, it's better to use a single variable to hold your collection of objects you're displaying in table: i.e.

```
// Define your model
struct Bar {
    var name: String
    var image: String
    var address: String
}

// Change your variables
var bars = [Bar]()
var selectedBar: Bar?
```

Second, you'd need to get a single `bar` object upon cell's selection. i.e.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    selectedBar = bars[indexPath.row]        
}
```

Upon segueing, you can inject it to your `detailsVC` like so:

```
details.selectedBar = selectedBar
```

You've complete `selectedBar` object to inflate your UI instead of just a `String`.

**Sample Addition:** I've created a sample that does the required functionality. Perform the pod installation as you pull the code. Here's what my database looks like:

[image]

**Repository:** https://github.com/HassanSE/FirebaseSample

Comment: if it is possible can you show full code example ) I have an issue when i am writting var bars = [Bar]()
var selectedBar: Bar?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I dont really get the Struct) Tried several ways, but I would still get an error)

Comment: Okay. You're basically trying to read from database and populating your table, tapping a cell would show details of a particular item. Correct? If I provide you sample with these features would that work?

Comment: Yes, please, samples will help a lot

Comment: I've edited my answer and added a sample. Please note that I'm using public rights for now. You can replace Firebase's plist file with your own and configure project accordingly.

Comment: Muhammad Hassan Thank you very much, it all worked. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Hey, based on your project, how is it possible to list an array of images in the folder of each child(e.g. if each bar will have a folder with the images of their offers) how can I show the array of images within the new tableview controller that is accessible by button from the detailViewController?) I am trying to list offer images array in the new tableview) Please, could your help me out with that ;) Thank you in advance.